# External links do not open on Tor browser

Tags: ubuntu

Running Ubuntu 20.10 and I have made Tor my default browser. It works well except when I click on external links (from an application, say ULauncher or a ebook reader).

Then I get an error message:

```
Tor Browser is already running but is not responding. To use Tor Browser you must first close the existing Tor Browser process, restart your device, or use a different profile.
```

[image: Screenshot of error message dialogue]

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because Tor Browser does not accept remote commands by default. See [here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/15185) and [here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/15981) for details. As mentioned in the tickets, you can work around this by starting the browser with the argument `--allow-remote`. You will need to add this option when you start the first instance and when trying to open a link from an external application. To facilitate this, you can create a simple bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER=$(dirname $0)
$FOLDER/start-tor-browser --allow-remote $@
```

Save this script in the Tor Browser folder (next to your `start-tor-browser` file and grant execution rights. You can then use this script as your default browser and everything should work as expected. **Keep in mind though, that the developers probably had a reason to make `--no-remote` the default option.** I think [the main concern](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12763) is, that apps on your system could open webpages via Tor and link your Tor identity with what they know about your system.